# using Helm behind a proxy

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to use Helm on new environment that only have access to Internte via Proxy.
How can I use Helm commands with proxy?
helm repo add ....
helm repo update

I tried to give proxy in command but I get following error:
Error: "helm repo add" requires 2 arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `HTTPS_PROXY=http://myproxy.com:8080` and then use helm commands.

example:

```
HTTPS_PROXY=http://myproxy.com:8080 helm repo add minio https://helm.min.io/
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the HTTPS_PROXY env var is case sensitive. So for example:

```
HTTPS_PROXY=$https_proxy
```

May resolve the helm repo add failure.