# Pact Broker Deploy with Helm fails: not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached

Tags: kubernetes-helm, pact, pact-broker

I'm following the instructions in [the documentation](https://docs.pact.io/pact_broker/kubernetes/readme), but getting this output:

```
C:\temp\helm-v3.11.1-windows-amd64\windows-amd64>helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
"bitnami" has been added to your repositories

C:\temp\helm-v3.11.1-windows-amd64\windows-amd64>helm repo add pact-broker https://pact-foundation.github.io/pact-broker-chart/
Error: looks like "https://pact-foundation.github.io/pact-broker-chart/" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Get "https://pact-foundation.github.io/pact-broker-chart/index.yaml": dial tcp 185.199.110.153:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Because the first repo add succeeds, I conclude that I have no problems with network connection or proxy. I can open the .yaml file mentioned in the error message, but the url without yaml gives http 404. I guess there is something wrong with the documentation.

Please advise..

Comment: Please explain why if you think this question should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but somehow our proxy was letting bitnami but not pact-broker. I added proxy environment variable as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75475449/using-helm-behind-a-proxy) and was able to add the chart.